# How to add device in VS code with flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am on macOS M1. I have installed Flutter and VS code, Android Studio, and Xcode. I have two accounts on it.
In the first account, I see the device in the bottom status bar. On the second device, there is "No Device". Even when I start the command palette and execute "Flutter: Launch Emulator" I get no device shown. On the second account, I opened Android Studio and added a device, Pixel 6, to it. But there is still no device in vs code. If I run flutter doctor I got no errors.

When I run: Flutter devices I get this:

```
3 connected devices:

sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)
macOS (desktop)             • macos         • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.4.1 22F82 darwin-arm64
Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.198

No wireless devices were found.
```

I have installed vs code and Android Studio with my first account. Could that be the reason?

How can I also have a device on my second account?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have Flutter and Android SDK installed.
2. Open your flutter project in VS code.
3. Click the device icon in the status bar in the lower right corner of vs code.
4. If you have already connected an Android device or emulator, it will be listed here. if not, click the + button to add a new device.
5. Select the type of device to add. For Android, you can choose either a Physical Device or an Android emulator.
6. When you add an Android emulator, you must select the Android SDK version and image of the device you want to use
7. After selecting the device, click add
8. The device will now be added to the list of devices in the status bar
9. You can now use Flutter on your device by pressing F5 or clicking the debug menu and selecting Start debugging

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. At 4. I click on "No Device" in the bottom status bar. Then a text field at the top opens saying: "Select a device to use". But there is nothing to choose. It looks like it is searching. There is a blue line moving from left to right. I do not see a + button.

Answer (score 0):

Somwhow it seems that the android SDK was not recognized even as `flutter doctor` give no errors.
I was able to solve it by first executing:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

And wonder why it is not there. Then executing:

```
flutter config --android-sdk [Path]
```

And then delete the project and cteate a new one.
Now I can choose a device in the status bar.